# HttpApplication.IntegratedModuleList is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, web-config, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having trouble calling CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(..) in the UrlAuthorizationModule.

It' seems like HttpApplication.IntegratedModuleList is null.

My web.config section around modules looks like

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="InitializationModule" type="EPiServer.Framework.Initialization.InitializationModule, EPiServer.Framework" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        <add name="UrlRewriteModule" type="EPiServer.Web.RoutingUrlRewriteModule, EPiServer" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        <add name="ShellRoutingModule" type="EPiServer.Shell.Web.Routing.ShellRoutingModule, EPiServer.Shell" />
        <add name="BusinessFoundationInitializeModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="Mediachase.Commerce.Core.Modules.BusinessFoundationInitializeModule, Mediachase.Commerce" />
        <add name="ProfileModule" type="EPiServer.Business.Commerce.HttpModules.ProfileModule, EPiServer.Business.Commerce" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
        <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
        <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        <add name="UrlRoutingHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <add name="ReportingHttpHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </handlers>
....
</system.webServer>
```

The problem arose when upgrading from MVC4 to MVC5, and the packages connected to this. I dont know if it has anything specific to do with this.

My nuget packages is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
    <package id="AuthorizeNet" version="1.8.10" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Castle.Core" version="3.3.3" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Castle.Windsor" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="EPiCode.SqlBlobProvider" version="1.4.2" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="EPiServer.CMS.Core" version="10.3.1" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="EPiServer.Commerce.Core" version="10.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="EPiServer.CommerceManager" version="10.2.2" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="EPiServer.Framework" version="10.3.1" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="EPiServer.Logging.Log4Net" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="log4net" version="2.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Lucene.Net" version="3.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Providers.Core" version="2.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common" version="10.0.40219.1" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" version="10.0.40219.1" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow" version="4.5.24" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="SharpZipLib" version="0.86.0" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="SlowCheetah" version="2.5.14" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="structuremap.web-signed" version="3.1.6.186" targetFramework="net45" />
    <package id="structuremap-signed" version="3.1.9.463" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

I don't know if it's a web.config thing, but I suspect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, the code ran before the application context had been set.
Had to check if the HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance == null